# Sample java project that produce artifacts when build with teamcity

Tags: java, teamcity

I don't know java, but trying to test a java project with teamcity for CI/CD, the problem that I can't trigger build to produce `artifacts` that is critical for another build configuration to deploy.

So can someone give a sample java project that can produce `artifacts` when building with teamcity?

EDIT: more details below:

tree of project:

```
    └───src
        └───main
            └───java
                └───com
                    └───mycompany
                        └──app
```

The last folder `app` contains a file named `App.java` with content as below:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        System.out.println("A NullPointerException is a drag...");
        Object myObject = null;
        /**
         * Checker prevents this from compiling...
         */
//        System.out.println("myObject: " + myObject.toString());
        /**
         * ... which is simply fantastic. It shows:
         *
         * error: [dereference.of.nullable] dereference of possibly-null
         * reference myObject
         *
         * http://checkerframework.org
         */
        System.out.println("... but thankfully, Checker has our back: http://checkerframework.org");
    }
```

I'm trying to build `hello` world project, copied form internet, I can't veriry this sourcecode and how it works.

The `pom.xml` for maven build in the same folder with `src`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
      <!-- This property will be set by the Maven Dependency plugin -->
      <annotatedJdk>${org.checkerframework:jdk8:jar}</annotatedJdk>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>checker</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
      <arguments>
        <argument>argument1</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
          <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
        </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <!-- This plugin will set the properties values using dependency information -->
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>properties</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <fork>true</fork>
              <!-- Add all the checkers you want to enable here -->
              <annotationProcessors>
                  <annotationProcessor>org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker</annotationProcessor>
              </annotationProcessors>
              <compilerArgs>
                  <!-- location of the annotated JDK, which comes from a Maven dependency -->
                  <arg>-Xbootclasspath/p:${annotatedJdk}</arg>
              </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I add this project under local git server, and push it to teamcity (add some spaces to sourcecode) to trigger build, the `build step` is from `auto-detected` build config feature of `maven` build step (I chose `maven` when adding new build step)

EDIT 2: when I trigger run build on teamcity, the build is successful but the `artifacts` is hidden, I need after build this project, it produces `.jar or .war` package in `artifacts`.

EDIT 3: with or without `**/*.jar` in `artifacts`, run build didn't produce `.jar` artifacts, below is the config:
[image]

Thanks for any helping. I stuck for couple days now.

Comment: your question is too broad. please provide details. how you do `build` of java project? what does it mean "i can't trigger build"? maybe you don't know how to build it?

Comment: I'll update the #1 in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to tell Team City where the build artifacts are. In the build configuration there is a field **(Arifact Paths)** which will take ant notation. for example show all jar/war files.

```
**/*.war
**/*.jar
```

This will scan the entire project for either a war or jar file. These would normally be placed in the `/target` folder that maven uses to build the source code.

Comment: Thanks, but how to have `*.jar` file in `artifacts` tab of teamcity web ui? I have another build config that will check the build success status of the previous build and also its `artifacts`.

Comment: So if you have another build configuration that uses this configuration, you'll need to set this as a dependency. You can state that it has a dependency on the artefact, and use the same rules as above. It might also be a good idea to set the previous build configuration as a build trigger.

Comment: Absolutely later build will be triggered on the success of previous build and look for `.jar` package to do somethine else, so I will have to put the same `**/*.jar` to have later build look for `.jar` in the same folder of previous one. Thanks, I'll try later and give feedback of success or not.

Comment: It didn't produce `.jar` artifact, I've just update the #1 with image.

Comment: What maven goal is your build server running on the project. You're using the shade plugin, which will generate you a fat jar on the package phase. You will need the build cycle to use package at least. You could run `mvn clean install`

Comment: I have `clean test` that's default when use `auto-detect` build steps, I'll change to `clean install` tomorrow and give feedback. Teamcity use `maven` tools to build and I don't want to involve/manually run `mvc`.

Comment: I did have `clean test compile` in goals, change to `clean install` did work. Thanks.

Comment: I have another question with the same project here, can you give a look? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52751319/5813693